# ag-Grid React applyTransaction is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using:

- "ag-grid-community": "^23.0.2"
- "ag-grid-enterprise": "^23.0.2"
- "ag-grid-react": "^23.0.3"

I use **getSelectedRows** (it returns the rows the selected rows ) then I try to use **applyTransaction** but it throws and error "gridApi.applyTransaction is not a function", the API is in the same scope, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was on a lower version: they add this feature on version 23.1.0

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=23.1.0

Comment: Thanks for following up to your own question. This helped me out.

Comment: What to do for version lower than that ? I have the same issue with ag-grid 17.1

Answer (score 4):

From [ag-grid changelogs](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/) we can see this:

[image]

So prior to ag-grid 23.1.0, we can use `api.updateRowData()` in place of `applyTransaction`